# Build Ionic code on desktop

Tags: ionic3

I am developing an Ionic app that will fit both iOS and android, but if I want to make the same software run on desktop computer what can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Ionic Framework` is based on `Angular` any software you build will run on any browser. You can even theme you application depending on what device it is running on (including on a desktop).

If you are planning to run your application on a browser you cannot utilise any of `Ionic Native`. Except for geolocation, that will work in browser.

In summary building an application with no native control will work on a Desktop, Android and iOS.

To test you application in browser run the command `ionic serve` in the `cli`

Comment: Cool, thanks! Very useful. A correlate question is: I know that there is a way (I will study which is the way) tu publish the app in apple store or play store. Is there a way I can pass this app to other desktop computers to run on browsers?

Comment: The best way is to run it like a website. You can rent out a server with a custom domain, this will let anyone to connect. If you don't want to rent a server there is another way.

Comment: Can you please post a link about how I can "run it like a website"?

Comment: In your Ionic project you should have a www folder this is your “website”. Here is a great article how to deploy a [website](https://www.codeschool.com/beginners-guide-to-web-development/deploying-your-first-website). Just one thing to remember ionic only works on Safari and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Now I have been able to upload my Ionic project in a hosting space named heroku, but I found out that it doesn't support pouchdb/couchdb synchronization. Can you please suggest me some hosting that allows this feature?

Comment: I have already put my database on an Aruba VPS. Now I am looking for a hosting website that can communicate with my VPS holding the database. Is Cloudant able to do this? Or is Cloudant a DB server alternative to my Aruba VPS?